# Insert to a table by selecting from a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, select, oledb

I have two questions about inserting to a SQL Server table directly from the resultset of a stored procedure.

I want to do two things:

1. the SP which I'm calling it to get resultset and the table I want to insert those resultset into are NOT in the same databases; Here, I have local database which insert into it and a SP which is called from a remote IP address. I want to know how should I declare the connection string in my Web.Config file so that it covers both the SP and the table I'm inserting into it because I want to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` clause which will select from the SP and puts the resultset in my local table.
2. There are some columns of my table which their value is not in the SP and I should put my own values on them. How can I perform this operation so that any row of my table could get a column value which is calculated by my own and is unrelated to the SP resultset values.

You answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, I want to know how should I declare the connection string in my Web.Config file

Basically, you set it up to connect to your local SQL Server. What you need to do is to make sure that the login to the local SQL Server has been set up with a LINKED SERVER login to the remote database, and the remote server has been added as a linked server to the local SQL Server. The linked server login is used to specify that when this local user connects to the particular remote server, it will use the login details specified, which must be given execute permission to the SP in question

Here is one place to start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

2, There are some columns of my table which their value is not in the SP and I should put my own values on them.

You have to channel through a temp table.  Let's say it provides 6 columns

```
INSERT #localtable (a,b,c,d,e,f)
EXEC remote.sql.dbo.SomeSProc 1, 'a'
```

#localtable should have the columns equal to the resultset
Then, insert from that temp table to the final destination

```
INSERT finaltable (a,b,x,c,d,y,e,f)
SELECT a,b, 1 , c,d, 'test' , e,f
FROM #localtable
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER – Select Columns from Stored Procedure Resultset

Very good point: 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/26/sql-server-select-columns-from-stored-procedure-resultset/

First we will create a sample stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SampleSP
AS
 SELECT 1 AS Col1, 2 AS Col2
UNION
 SELECT 11, 22
 GO
```

Now we will create a table where we will temporarily store the result set of stored procedures. We will be using INSERT INTO and EXEC command to retrieve the values and insert into temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
GO
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC SampleSP
 GO
```

Next we will retrieve our data from stored procedure.

```
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
GO
```

Finally we will clean up all the objects which we have created.

```
DROP TABLE #TempTable
DROP PROCEDURE SampleSP
 GO
```

Comment: How is this any different than the accepted answer? Also, this answer doesn't address the issue of the Stored Procedure being on a remote server.